# Android Navigation Drawer Level

Tags: java, android, arrays, layout, navigation-drawer

I am having some problem with navigation drawer in Android. So these are the codes with me:

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends FragmentActivity {
private String[] drawerListViewItems;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

protected DrawerLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout actContent;

@Override
public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {

    fullLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.navigation_drawer, null); // Your base layout here
    actContent = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.act_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
    drawerLayout, 
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
    R.string.drawer_open, 
    R.string.drawer_close 
    );
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    drawerListView.bringToFront();
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        switch (position) {
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
    }
}
}
```

And my xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:divider="#CCCCCC"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/act_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the string file where I declare the words for navigation drawer item:

```
<string-array name="items">
    <item>Dashboard</item>
    <item>Account</item>
    <item>Setting</item>
    <item>Recurring</item>
    <item>Budget</item>
</string-array>
```

But with these code, the navigation drawer level is only one. What I am trying to do is there will be still sub item under Dashboard, Setting and Budget.

I wonder how to modify it so that the navigation drawer could take in one more level of items.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
// private ListView mDrawerList;

private ExpandableListView mDrawerList;

private LinearLayout navDrawerView;

CustomExpandAdapter customAdapter;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mAnalyzeEventSelection;
private int selectedPosition;

List<SampleTO> listParent;

HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    navDrawerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navDrawerView);
    mAnalyzeEventSelection = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.analyzeEvent_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    listParent = new ArrayList<SampleTO>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Navigation Drawer of Flight starts
    listParent.add(new SampleTO(getString(R.string.createEventDrawer), R.drawable.sun));
    listParent.add(new SampleTO(getString(R.string.analyzeEventDrawer), R.drawable.solar_system));
    listParent.add(new SampleTO(getString(R.string.qrCodeDrawer), R.drawable.moon));

    listDataChild.put(getString(R.string.createEventDrawer), new ArrayList<String>());
    listDataChild.put(getString(R.string.qrCodeDrawer), new ArrayList<String>());

    listDataChild.put(getString(R.string.analyzeEventDrawer), Arrays.asList(mAnalyzeEventSelection));

    customAdapter = new CustomExpandAdapter(this, listParent, listDataChild);
    // setting list adapter
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
    mDrawerLayout, 
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
    R.string.drawer_open, 
    R.string.drawer_close 
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

   /* if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }*/
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition));
            parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

            String parentTitle = ((SampleTO) customAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition)).getTitle();

            if (parentTitle.equals(getString(R.string.createEventDrawer))){
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Create Event",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setTitle(mAnalyzeEventSelection[selectedPosition]);
            }
            else if (parentTitle != getString(R.string.analyzeEventDrawer)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerView);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

            selectItem(childPosition);

            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navDrawerView);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    selectedPosition = position;
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerView);

    switch(selectedPosition){
    case 0:
        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this,
                "Event Pop",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 1:
        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this,
                "Buffer",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }

    setTitle(mAnalyzeEventSelection[selectedPosition]);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}   
}
```

And my string file:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer Example</string>

<string name="createEventDrawer">Create Event</string>
<string name="analyzeEventDrawer">Analyze Event</string>  
<string-array name="analyzeEvent_array">
    <item>Past Event Population</item>
    <item>Buffer</item>     
</string-array>
<string name="qrCodeDrawer">QR Code Scan</string>

<string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
<string name="action_websearch">Web search</string>
<string name="app_not_available">Sorry, there\'s no web browser available</string>
<string name="_11">11</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Change ListView to Expandablelistview.
2. Add subitems  for the group items required.

Example :[Custom Navigation Drawer](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/05/android-custom-navigation-drawer-using.html)

Comment: Would you mind to provide some code examples which could implement into my solution above?

Comment: @IWasSoLost, check i have added example link

Comment: Thanks but is there any ways to change your selectItem() to use intent instead of fragment? Also I did selected Sun and Moon but nothing happened after that. Is it supposed to behave in that way?

Comment: Also is there any way to use switch() like what I've did previously on the navigation drawer items? Because I don't quite understand your codes. :(

Comment: Do you want to open new activity? Then go ahead with intent. There is no complexity in the code, Just go line by line and map with you're code. You can understand easily

Comment: Can you please help me take a look at my codes? I've modified it but the navigation drawer is not showing.

Comment: I solved it already and yeah, looking through the codes line by line made me understand how it works! Thanks! Anyway, was thinking is there any way to change the child list view background color to grey color?

Comment: In getChildView of adapter, use the xml with grey background color.

Comment: I tried with grey/gray but it told me color not found :(

Comment: Use @android:color/darker_gray or else create your own color in resource file and use

Comment: Sorry but to trouble you again. Let say I wanted to use red and pink color. Is there any android default color for me to use?

Comment: Because I not sure how should I declare my own color code and use for this part: <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>

Comment: Do you have any idea how to change the text color of navigation drawer? Because I tried to put android:textColor="#FFFFFF" but it just stays as black color

Comment: Where are you putting android:textColor="#FFFFFF"?

Comment: ExpandableListView which with an id nav_left_drawer. Am I putting at the correct space? Because I wan every navigation drawer items to be in white

Comment: Hello! Another question is let's say I created another activity class which extends activity class. By doing this, the new activity class that I've just created does not have the navigation drawer shown. Do you have any ideas?